# can't access to map element (c++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, format

I have a very strange problem :
I am reading trough a xml file and put all the attribute/value inside a `map<const char*, const char*> myMap` as key/value.
My problem is that I can access and print all the keys/values via an iterator, but I can't access it directly `(*mymap)["key"]` : the program crashes during the run.

Even stranger: i can add a key that is already inside the map, and when I iterate through the map and print it, I can see both of those identical keys with different values !

My guess is that my xml file might have a string format slightly different that the usual one, so the keys seems identical as strings but they might not be in binary format...

Do you have any idea about that problem ?

Comment: Replace `char*` with `std::string`. Pointers make lousy keys. And `mymap` is an invalid pointer. Avoid pointers.

Comment: Given the type of `mymap` your syntax of indexing out of it is completely valid. It sounds more like `mymap` or something is `NULL`. You're probably trying to dereference a null pointer or something. We cannot tell you much more without seeing your code.

Comment: Is you map actually `map<char* c, char* c>` or `map<char*, char*>`?

Comment: Using a pointer as a key uses the actual *pointer* as the key, not what it points to.

Comment: actually my map is `map<const char*, const char*>`

Comment: @molbdnilo : replacing `char*`  by `std::string` worked. Thanks all of you for your help !
(should someone write a proper answer that I can select to close the issue ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pointer to char (not a c-string) as a key. And the pointer is actually an address in memory, so when you do the

```
(*mymap)["key"]
```

String literal "key" will be placed on top of the stack as an array of four elements. As your key is pointe the address of the first element will be passed to the operator brackets. This value will have nothing in common with what you have stored as a key earlier and a new value will be created for this pointer on the stack and it will be a null pointer.

Here's what happens when you trivially compare c-strings

```
const char* a = "key"; // Something like 0xac22f214 <- address on the stack
const char* b = "key"; // 0xac22f218
a == b; // False
a < b; // True
a > b; // False
```

For your purposes it's better to use std::string and figure out how pointers work.